# Laravel store user critical information in session or cookies?

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I use **Laravel Framwork** for all my php projects, and I am wondering if **Laravel 5*** store user critical information in `session` or `cookies`. I mean in server side or client side.

Comment: Passwords are saved in the Database, whatever that database might be, but not in cookies nor in session.

Comment: password does not stored in cookies or session. with laravel framework, it will encrypt the password the moment the data is pass into database.

Comment: read [Laravel Authentication Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) for more details

Comment: sorry guys I will edit the question so that you could get my point

Comment: Laravel will store anything whereever you tell it to store it.

Comment: as I said, if you read the documentation for the Authentication, you will see, the LoginController will compare the hashe of the password the user provides with the hash of the password stored in the database. If they match, an authenticated session will be started for the user